# Comparison between TextInputFormat vs Avro

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, avro, hadoop-streaming, file-format

I am a bit new to Hadoop and its file formats. I have a below query related to it.

In a 4 datanode cluster only one datanode is having all the data that needs to be processed for any problem (its a very large volume of data, that needs to be processed in parallel using MapReduce Framework) and rest of the 3 datanodes are empty. So based on the data locality how differently Avro and TextInputFormat will act on the data to consume/parse it in a faster than other.

I know the basic feature/ advantages of Avro over TextFileFormat

```
**Compact** − To make the best use of network bandwidth, which is the most scarce resource in a data center.
**Fast** − Since the communication between the nodes is crucial in distributed systems, the serialization and deserialization process should be quick, producing less overhead.
**Extensible** − Protocols change over time to meet new requirements, so it should be straightforward to evolve the protocol in a controlled manner for clients and servers.
**Interoperable** − The message format should support the nodes that are written in different languages.
```

But I am looking for an Answer in a more specific and descriptive way to answer this particular situation. I will appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Still looking for someone to reply :)

Comment: may be http://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro you can help me